# initialize immutable struct from dict

Tags: dictionary, struct, parameters, julia

I have an immutable struct that has default values (thanks Parameters.jl), and I would like to create instances of this struct from dictionaries that I have (originally these come from a JSON file). However, while I know the set of possible keys in these dictionaries, not every dictionary will have the same keys. I'm struggling to figure out how to algorithmically turn these dicts into instances of my immutable struct. How can I do this?

For example, I have:

```
@with_kw struct Mystruct
    id::String
    mass::Float64
    names::Vector{String}=Vector{String}()
    elements::Vector{String}=Vector{String}()
end
```

and many dicts, each of which could have different keys. They'll all have `id` and `mass` (which is why there're no default values for those), but each dict may or may not have `names`, and `elements`.

It seems like if I was using a mutable struct this would be easy because I could just initialize the instance, and then use `setfield!` after the fact--but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this before a mutable struct is "initialized".

Related: [Pass arguments to @kwdef struct programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108477/pass-arguments-to-kwdef-struct-programmatically?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this simple struct without parameters, you can just construct a new one like this:

```
julia> kwargs = Dict(:id=>"test", :mass=> 1.)
Dict{Symbol,Any} with 2 entries:
  :id   => "test"
  :mass => 1.0

julia> Mystruct(;kwargs...)
Mystruct
  id: String "test"
  mass: Float64 1.0
  names: Array{String}((0,))
  elements: Array{String}((0,))
```

Comment: Thank you! I had just discovered this (finally) before you posted. It's worth noting (for future readers) that this will only work when the dict has `Symbol`s as keys. So if your dict keys aren't symbols, you need to convert them to symbols before doing this.

Comment: Which version of Julia are you using? I am on `1.1.1` and I get a `MethodError: no method matching Mystruct(; id="test", mass=1.0)`

Comment: I am on `1.3`. I haven't tested it on `1.1`