# In julia, where struct argument names are coming from?

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I have a newbie question. What I understand that a struct will have fields and once pass them by order. Like :

```
julia> struct Foo
           bar
           baz
       end

julia> foo = Foo(1, 2)
Foo(1, 2)
```

In something like Makie, the main struct is `Figure()`. All the tutorials are showing customized arguments like backgroundcolor, resolution ...etc.

```
f = Figure(backgroundcolor = :tomato)
```

But in the docstring, there is no mentioning for these keywords.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate of: [Pass arguments to @kwdef struct programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108477/pass-arguments-to-kwdef-struct-programmatically)

But to answer your question, as shown there you can have keyword fields by placing the `Base.@kwdef` macro before `struct`, i.e.:

```
Base.@kwdef struct Foo
    bar = nothing
    baz = nothing
end
```

Then doing `Foo(baz=3)` returns `Foo(nothing,3)` etc.

To answer your question about what they do in `Makie`, here is their relevant bit of code for making Figures (from their GitHub source code):

```
function Figure(; kwargs...)

    kwargs_dict = Dict(kwargs)
    padding = pop!(kwargs_dict, :figure_padding, theme(:figure_padding))
    scene = Scene(; camera=campixel!, kwargs_dict...)
    padding = convert(Observable{Any}, padding)
    alignmode = lift(Outside ∘ to_rectsides, padding)

    layout = GridLayout(scene)

    on(alignmode) do al
        layout.alignmode[] = al
        GridLayoutBase.update!(layout)
    end
    notify(alignmode)

    f = Figure(
        scene,
        layout,
        [],
        Attributes(),
        Ref{Any}(nothing)
    )
    # set figure as layout parent so GridPositions can refer to the figure
    # if connected correctly
    layout.parent = f
    f
end
```

They create a dictionary based on the keyword arguments, then pass those manually to the Figure struct, which is defined as:

```
struct Figure
    scene::Scene
    layout::GridLayoutBase.GridLayout
    content::Vector
    attributes::Attributes
    current_axis::Ref{Any}

    function Figure(args...)
        f = new(args...)
        current_figure!(f)
        f
    end
end
```

So they use the `Figure` function to access the keyword arguments and then pass the appropriate keywords to the `Figure` struct.

Comment: You can use `Base.@kwdef`, but it's not necessary. The basic approach is to simply define constructors, that is, functions like `Foo(;bar=nothing, baz=nothing) = Foo(bar, baz)`. The `@kwdef` is simply there for convenience.